# Automatically sum input data put into an ngFor with Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to add the values ​​found inside inputs automatically without making any submit, and I tried to obtain the data through an array and I could not.

```
    <ion-card-content *ngFor="let info of data; let i = index ">
              <ion-label><i>{{info.name}}:</i></ion-label>
              <ion-item class="inputItem" >
                <ion-input (ngModel)="info.id" name="{{info.id}}"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
   </ion-card-content>
  <ion-label>{{total}}</ion-label>
```

example of data:

```
data=[
{"id":"1","name":"name1"},
{"id":"2","name":"name2"},
{"id":"3",,"name":"name3"},...
]
```

Comment: What does your data look like?. This can probably be achieved with an array map function.

Comment: The information of each data has a name and an id but I do not know the size of the data that can arrive, that is, there may be 3, 4, 5 ... but what I want to do is add each input by info, that the user writes for show you the total you are adding

Comment: Yes but what is that data structure. I presume you work with an array and there are N number of a certain data set?

Comment: data=[
{"id":"1","name":"name1"},
{"id":"2","name":"name2"},
{"id":"3",,"name":"name3"},...
] 
this dataset comes from a query

Comment: do u want the count of the item like {{ data.length }} ?

Answer (score 0):

Using TypeScript and document object, you can get the values of all the ion-input inside a container:

a) Place your inputs inside a container `div`

```
<div id="inputContainer">
  <ion-card-content *ngFor="let info of data; let i = index ">
              <ion-label><i>{{info.name}}:</i></ion-label>
              <ion-item class="inputItem" >
                <ion-input type="number" (ionInput)="getSum()" name="{{info.id}}"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
   </ion-card-content>
</div>
 <ion-label>{{total}}</ion-label>
```

b) On each input event call the getSum() function

```
getSum()
  {
    let container=document.getElementById('inputContainer');
    let inputElements=container.getElementsByClassName('native-input');
    this.total=0;
    let eachInput:HTMLInputElement;
    for(let i=0;i<inputElements.length;i++)
    {
      eachInput=<HTMLInputElement>inputElements.item(i);
      this.total+=Number(eachInput.value);
    }
  }
```

**Explaination:** Here, we are getting all the native `input` tags and accessing their `value` attribute. `(ionInput)` event will trigger each time you input a value in any of the `ion-input`